# PHP - How can i reach home folder

Tags: php

i want to reach my local home folder. For example:

`"folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/index.php"`  This is the location.

I have to reach "folder1"

When i use dirname() it seems `"folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5"` this path.

How can i reach "folder1"?

PS: if the path is `"folder1/folder2/folder3/index.php"`  again i have to reach "folder1"

If u help me i will be glad. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) and [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$dirname = "folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5";
list($first) = explode('/', $dirname);
echo $first;//folder1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood you correctly, but you can use:

```
$folder1 = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../';
```

Use as many `/../` as you need. Each use of this will take you to the directory "higher". You can also use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of `/`. But you may not have the rights to write to or read data from such a directory.